# Replace oldest value in list?

Tags: c#, queue

I'm making an application whose job is to generate two lists and display them on demand. As well as update the values every second.

I need to update the list in such a way so that the oldest value in the list is replaced first. How would I do that? Below is my code in it's current state.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Data_Collector
{
    //What is needed?
    //Need to generate a list of both metric values, and imperial values.
    //Need to be able to display a list 

    public class IMeasuringDevice_Helper
    {
        private int limit; //Limits the list size.
        private float RNDouble;

        public void MetricValueGenerator()
        {

            limit = limit + 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Limit Level = " + limit);


            if (limit <= 10)
            {
                List<float> MetricValueGenerated = new List<float>();

                Random rnd = new Random();
                float rndINT = rnd.Next(1, 10);
                RNDouble = rndINT / 10;
                Console.WriteLine(RNDouble);
                MetricValueGenerated.Add(RNDouble);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("limit reached");
            }

        }

        public void ImperialValueGenerator()
        {
            //TODO
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a FIFO datastructure or a circular queue.

Comment: As @Pierre-LucPineault mentioned, a FIFO structure makes sense, such as a [queue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You will need a [Queue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx) for this, but you will need to extend it.  The default C# Queue is First-In, First-Out (exactly the semantic you want), but does not subscribe to limits the way your code currently handles them.  It simply grows by a growth factor if full.

So you will want to extend the `Queue` object and override the `Enqueue` method to do what you want.  It will probably look a little like this:

```
public class BoundedQueue<T> : Queue<T>
{
   private readonly int _bound;

   public BoundedQueue(int bound)
   {
       _bound = bound;
   }

   public new void Enqueue(T item)
   {
       if(Count >= _bound)
       {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("limit reached");
            // If simply throwing an exception isn't cool, you can also do the following to pop off the oldest item:
            // base.Dequeue();
       }
       base.Enqueue(item);
   }
}
```

The only thing to be aware of is when you turn this into some other kind of object for display, you may see it in the reverse order you expect, as the oldest item will be at the 'top' of the queue.  You can sort this out by simply calling the `Reverse()` method that works with most LINQ-enabled objects.

Comment: The above should work properly but I happen to be away from my dev env right now and cannot check to make sure it compiles.  Please alert me if there's some sort of syntax error or other problem and I'll happily update my answer!

Comment: There is a built in way to have a queue with a limited size in .NET, if you create a `BlockingCollection` backed by a `ConcurrentQueue` you can set the max size.

Comment: I like the method you use (and it seems to be the most popular one thus far) but is there any other way to do what I'm looking for? I just feel like the Quque is a bit overkill for my purposes. Also I did try the code you had and it gave [a ton of errors](http://pastebin.com/QdQjzTx8) (but you're probably on mobile so I feel your pain :P).

Comment: @Sie Thanks - I got back to my main computer and fixed stuff up.  Looks a lot better now.  I am going to look at the suggestion given by Scott Chamberlain and see about expanding my answer a bit!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do any class extensions as @YYY has suggested, pretty much replace `List` with `Queue`, replace `.add()` with `.Enqueue()` and instead of `oldestValue = yourList[oldestIndex]` use `oldestValue = yourQueue.Dequeue()`.

Aside from your question, your variables should start with a lowercase letter, and `RNDouble = rndINT / 10;` is going to end up = 0 most of the time because you should divide by 10.0 instead of 10.

Ok so I was bored... (also I wouldn't go with this approach, but I'm guessing you're learning and haven't been taught about Queues, so this might help with Lists):

```
public class MeasuringDevice_Helper
{
    private const int LIMIT = 10;   // This is a constant value, so should be defined IN_CAPS in class definition
    List<double> metricValues = new List<double>(LIMIT);    // This needs to be at class level so it doesn't get lost
    Random rnd = new Random();  // This is used frequently so define at class level

    public void GenerateMetricValue()  // This is now named like the action it performs
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Current metric values = " + metricValues.Count);

        if (metricValues.Count < LIMIT)     // This should just be < not <=
        {
            float rndInt = rnd.Next(1, 10);
            double rndDouble = rndInt / 10.0;   // An Int divided by Int will = Int
            Console.WriteLine("Added " + rndDouble);
            metricValues.Add(rndDouble);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("limit reached");
        }
    }

    public double PopOldestMetricValue()
    {
        double value = metricValues[0];
        metricValues.RemoveAt(0);
        return value;
    }
}
```